# Pycharm - using remote Docker container as interpreter

Tags: docker, ssh, pycharm, ssh-tunnel

I have a remote machine, with a running Docker container, and I want to set-up Pycharm to use the Python interpreter within the container. So, the situation is something like this:

```
    PyCharm
      ^
local_machine -->  remote_machine
                         |
                         V
                   docker_container
```

On the local machine, I have a ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host remote_machine
        HostName remote_machine_ip
        User user_name

Host docker_vie01_00
    HostName docker_container_ip_address
    User root
    ProxyJump remote_machine
```

I can ssh to the docker container from my local machine using:

```
ssh docker_vie01_00
```

I'm asked for a password (I configured the Docker root password in the Dockerfile that I used to create the container), and I'm in the container.

Now I'm trying to configure Pycharm to do the same.
If I check the SSH Configurations section, everything seems to be working fine:

[image]
[image]

However, using the same SSH configuration for the deployment fails:

[image]
[image]

I tried creating the interpreter using the SSH server:
[image]

Which seems to be successful, this is the output:

```
Successfully connected to root@docker_vie01_00:22

> pwd
/root
Command finished with exit code 0

Checking rsync connection...
/usr/bin/rsync -n -e "ssh -p 22 " root@docker_vie01_00:

root@172.17.0.3's password: 

drwx------        4096 2023/05/04 15:12:02 .
-rw-------          15 2023/05/04 15:12:02 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--        3106 2019/12/05 15:39:21 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--         161 2019/12/05 15:39:21 .profile
drwxrwxr-x        4096 2023/04/17 11:26:00 .aws
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2023/04/17 17:00:43 .cache
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2023/04/17 17:00:37 .npm
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2023/05/04 15:10:10 work
Process finished with exit code 0

Starting introspection for Python...
> echo ${SHELL}
/bin/bash
Command finished with exit code 0
> /usr/bin/which python3
/usr/bin/python3
Command finished with exit code 0
> echo ${HOME}
/root
Command finished with exit code 0

Introspection completed
```

But then, Pycharm can't navigate the container folders to let me find the Python interpreter:

[image]

I also tried setting the interpreter path manually, but then it seems that nothing is loaded:
[image]

If I try to run the code, I get this error window:
[image]

Comment: Were you able to find the solution ?

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told on the PyCharm forums that this is likely to be a bug, so not much to do at the moment. However, if you use PyCharm Pro, there's a new Beta functionality which allows you to SSH into remote hosts...it's the "Remote Development → SSH" option, accessible through the "Welcome to PyCharm" window

[image]

Selecting New Project, you can select between the possible SSH configurations available in PyCharm (you can set them up through Setting → Tools → SSH Configurations). The whole thing is actually much more similar to how VS Code works. It downloads some helpers and open a remote PyCharm instance directly on the remote machine, and you can work there. I tested it, and it works in remote docker containers as well.

Another alternative is to use VS Code, I kinda like how this remote deployment is implemented there.